# Run some javascript lines before the rest

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            console.log("1");
        });
        console.log("2");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I ran this on Google Chrome, the console logs 2 before 1. I know removing document.ready will fix this problem but I want it to run only once. But in my problem, `console.log("1")` actually replaces a server call which executes after `console.log("2")`. I really hope I am making sense (apologies if it doesn't) as English is not my first language.

Is there any way I can get it to print 1 before 2?

Thanking you in advance.

EDIT: console.log("1") replaces data received from the server and console.log("2") replaces a UI component which views this data received. Maybe I should've said this earlier. Apologies.

Comment: @Rajesh The OP knows that

Comment: You can look into other events like `DOMContentLoaded`. This will fire before `document.ready`

Comment: Can you not simply put both inside the document ready function?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please give us a more representative example of what you are trying to do instead of these two `console.log` lines. As it is currently written, the answer to your question is "No.".

Comment: @JohnHascall I could but what if I replaced console.log("2") with an onclick function and need it to run more than once? Would it still work?

Comment: you should put both in $(document).ready and if  console.log("1") is an ajax call then  console.log("2") should be executed in success callback. you can also bind console.log("2") to click event using jquery in $(document).ready. Where is the confusion?

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer I don't know what _"console.log("1") replaces data received from the server"_ or _"console.log("2") replaces a UI component which views this data "_ means. Could you please modify your code example to give us a rough idea of what the code looks like? I am having a hard time picturing what the code actually does.

Comment: The call to update the UI should probably be tied to the completion of the call which fetched the data (eg in its "success" handler), but w/o the actual code it's hard to give you a concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this html attribute:

```
<body onload="somescript()">
```

This will execute your code immediately after the page is loaded.

```
function somescript() {
    console.log("1");
}
```

Or if you just want to run some script before the other one you can do this:

```
<body onload="init()">
function init() {
   console.log("1"); // Do your first code here
   next(); // Call function which contains the code that should be executed next
}

function next() {
 // Do your next code here 
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. But what if instead of console.log("2") it was accessing some data from somescript.js?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope this will help you. :)